# TLS version used by Outlook add in

Tags: .net, outlook-addin, tls1.2

Not an expert in .NET and in Outlook add in development. However have to look for an issue in an existing outlook add in :).

Our outlook add in makes communication with a Java based server over HTTPS. My outlook add in is on 4.5.1 .NET version.

Right now our server supports TLS 1.0 , 1.1 and 1.2 .

However i see this code in our outlook add in

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

As i understand this code ensures that communication can happen depending on the TLS version supported by server as per this 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netcore-3.1

I don't know if the communication should  have happened over the highest secure platform in my case if both client and server both support 1.2.

But still i see the communication is happening over less than < 1.2. Not sure why this is happening.  As per the documentation i understand that OS setting does not influence the TLS version for .NET versions less than 4.7.

And also is the above code correct and ensures that the communication should happen over the highest secure version. ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My outlook add in is on 4.5.1 .NET version.

The default `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` in both .NET 4.0/4.5 is `SecurityProtocolType.Tls|SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3`. But if you use the following code at startup early then everything should go smoothly:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

> But still i see the communication is happening over less than < 1.2. Not sure why this is happening.

You need to check out settings on the server-side. I'd suggest using Fiddler to see what is going on at the low-level and why a lower TLS version is picked up.